# How should my game characters store their abilities/spells?

Tags: architecture, python, oop, roguelikes

I'm new to game development and a bit confused about how to effectively store an object's access to certain spells/abilities.

The player and mob objects are all generated from the same class. However, each object may have access to different abilities and spells. How do I keep track of a specific object's access to these?

Example: My player object might have access to *Fireball* and *Haste*, while a goblin might have access to *Confusion*.

I followed [the RogueBasin Python Libtcod tutorial](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_Roguelike_Tutorial,_using_python%2Blibtcod), and I understand how to attach a spell function to scroll use. I'm just not sure how to emulate a character memorizing a spell and using it as an ability.

Comment: Thinking aloud: I'd make a spell class with `string name`, `string description`, `number manaCost` and `lambda activate`, then give instances of it to each creature whenever necessary. Would that work? (Have you encountered lambdas in Python before?)

Comment: @Anko I think that would work. I have not encountered lambdas before, no.

Comment: Related: Here's [a Unity-specific question about a particular style of implementing this idea](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46819/making-characters-skills-and-abilities-as-commands-good-practice?rq=1) and [a similar C#-focused question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62974/c-design-for-ability-system?rq=1), as well as [this question on more general abilities, like ones that work over time](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51597/what-is-the-best-design-pattern-to-apply-effects-and-abilities?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to have spell objects hold some reference to the in-code action you want that spell to do.

Python's first-class functions make this quite nice (I'll assume Python 2.7.x):

```
class Spell:
    def __init__(self, name, description, activationFunction):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.activationFunction = activationFunction
    def cast(self, gameState):
        return self.activationFunction(self, gameState)

# Create a function to be called when the spell is cast. Give it as many
# parameters as you like.
def activationFunction(thisSpell, gameState):
    print thisSpell.name, 'was cast at game state', gameState

# Pass the function to a spell when instantiating it
fireballSpell = Spell('Fireball','standard spam spell', activationFunction)

# Cast the spell (with a dummy value representing the gameState parameter)
fireballSpell.cast("zero")
```

This prints

```
Fireball was cast at game state zero
```

You could then store instances of `Spell` in some class `Creature` if you like. You could add a `caster` parameter to every spell to which the creature passes `self`, or whatever other parameters you'd like.

Instead of `def`ing the `activationFunction`, you could also create an anonymous function with `lambda`. (Though [only if it fits on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233448/no-multiline-lambda-in-python-why-not)… Sorry if I got your hopes up.)

---

For language-completeness:

In JavaScript, Lua, CL, and other [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)-languages or languages with [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), the above works with few conceptual modifications.

For a similar idea in C#, Java, C++ and [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)-languages, the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is a good analogue for this. (Some even write Python in this style. I wouldn't bother.)

In C or other [system programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming_language) you *could* use [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html), but those can quickly get fiddly to work with. It may just be best to declare one big function `struct SpellResult castSpell(...)` that takes all spell parameters, then `switch`es on a passed-in `enum spellType` specifying which particular spell was meant. Values of that `enum` could then be stored by other game objects, for passing to `castSpell`.