# Design pattern that can be used for data driven ability system

Tags: design-patterns, data-driven

What are recommended design patterns for designing data-driven attribute system with data-driven abilities that would apply effect on target based on source attributes.

I have looked at following threads:

- [Making character's skills and abilities as commands, good practice?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46819/making-characters-skills-and-abilities-as-commands-good-practice)
- [C# Design for Ability System](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62974/c-design-for-ability-system)

and tutorial:

- https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-composite-design-pattern-for-an-rpg-attributes-system--gamedev-243

What is the best design pattern to apply effects and abilities?
Making character's skills and abilities as commands, good practice?
It seems that command + composite pattern composition is the most recommended.

Are there any recommended design pattern compositions that would serve the purpose?